# String replace throws error with $ sign

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm having an issue with replacing a string in java...

the line is:

```
subject = subject.replaceAll("\\[calEvent\\]", calSubject);
```

This line doesn’t work with $ sign in calSubject.

what the subject variable is, a dynamic subject line variable from a file. for example like so:
Calnot = [calEvent]

what i am trying to do is replace the calEvent place holder with the subject variable. but how i did it does not work because it crashes when the subject contains a $ sign.

any idea how I can do this so it won't break if the subject contains a $ sign or any characters for that matter?

Comment: When you say it crashes, what do you mean? Do you have a stack trace or does it simply not replace anything?

Comment: Are you getting IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: error is: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 3

Comment: @OakvilleWork which is logical, if it interprets the dollar sign as a capturing group reference, it tries to replace it with the corresponding group, if there are no such group, it throws an out-of-bound exception.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's because the dollar sign is a special character in a replacement string, use `Matcher.quoteReplacement()` to escape this kind of character.

```
subject = subject.replaceAll("\\[calEvent\\]", Matcher.quoteReplacement(calSubject));
```

From the doc of `String.replaceAll()` :

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use
>   `Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)` to suppress the special
>   meaning of these characters, if desired.

Note that the dollar sign is used to refer to the corresponding capturing groups in the regular expression (`$0`, `$1`, etc.).

**EDIT**

`Matcher.quoteReplacement()` has been introduced in Java 1.5, if you're stuck in Java 1.4 you have to escape `$` manually by replacing it with `\$` inside the string. But since `String.replaceAll()` would also take the `\` and the `$` as special characters you have to escape them once and you also have to escape all `\` once more for the Java runtime.

```
("$", "\$") /* what we want */
("\$", "\\\$") /* RegExp engine escape */
("\\$", "\\\\\\$") /* Java runtime escape */
```

So we get :

```
calSubject = calSubject.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$");
```

Comment: hi thanks so much for the suggestion.. the program uses java 1.4, and it doesn't seem to be working. hard to say because i can't debug it locally. just using logs for solving it. does java 1.4 not support:
Matcher.quoteReplacement?

Comment: Is there any mention in the java regex documentation that a dollar sign is used to refer to the capturing groups?

Comment: Yes, in the Javadoc of [Matcher#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)) : `Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences`.

Answer (score 5):

if you don't need the `regex` feature, you can consider to use this method of String class:
[replace(CharSequence target,CharSequence replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

It saves your "escape" backslashes as well.

api doc:

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the **literal target
>   sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence**. The
>   replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for
>   example, replacing "aa" with "b" in the string "aaa" will result in
>   "ba" rather than "ab".

Comment: can you provide an example of this?

Comment: That overload of the `replace()` method was added in JDK 1.5, and the OP is stuck with JDK 1.4.  And you can't use [`replace(char, char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) because the new value is not a single `char`.

Comment: @AlanMoore when I posted, OP didn't mention any information about 1.4. but you are right, this method is there since 1.5.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of replaceAll:

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use
>   java.util.regex.Matcher.quoteReplacement to suppress the special
>   meaning of these characters, if desired.

And in Matcher.replaceAll

> Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as
>   described above, and backslashes are used to escape literal characters
>   in the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really understand your question but try

```
subject = subject.replaceAll("\\[calEvent\\]", Matcher.quoteReplacement(calSubject));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
Matcher.quoteReplacement(calEvent);
```